# Jordan Normal Form, Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

Can someone please suggest a step-by-step method for finding the Jordan Normal Form of an nxn matrix.

(An example would be really helpful please)

Thanks!

Comment: Hopefully you already have a serious background in basic linear algebra, otherwise this might take quite a while and, imo, this is unfeasible in this site. You need linear maps, eigenvalues, eigenvectors, eigenspaces, algebraic and geometric multiplicites, characteristic and minimal polynomials of a linear map... If you haven't yet studied *any* of these subjects you better wait until you do in your linear algebra course.

Comment: Hi, yes I know about algebraic and geometric multiplicities etc., but I was hoping to check whether there is a good step by step method I should use when finding the JNF. Thanks!

Comment: @U There is: evaluate your map's char. polynomial, perhaps first by expressing it as a matrix wrt some basis.       Evaluate then this polynomial's roots which are the map's eigenvalues, and find each such eigenvalue's eigenspace. Iff the dimension of each corresponding eigenspace equals the alg. multiplicity of that eigenvalue is your map diagonalizable, otherwise it is not and you will have as many blocks of that eigenvalue in the JNF as the corresponding exponent of that eigenvalue's factor in the *minimal* pol.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! If there aren't enough eigenvectors, i.e. you can't diagonalize, do you just use the corresponding standard basis vectors?

Comment: @U I'm not sure what you mean "enough eigenvectors". It is **not necessary** that an $\;n\times n\;$ matrix has $\;n\;$ *different* eigenvalues for it to be diagonalizable...it is sufficient, though. Anyway, if you don't have enough eigenvectors to get a basis you must then use "generalized eigenvectors" . Google it.

Comment: @DonAntonio, are you right about the number of blocks? What you say say doesn't seem right for the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ whose minimal poly is $X^2$ but there's just one block. The only algorithm I know involves calculating all the $\dim\ker (A-\lambda I)^{s}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Rats, I can't understand how come I wrote that. Of course it is wrong. What is true is that **the size** of the largest Jordan block in the JNF is the exponent of its factor in the min. pol. Thanks.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I was very, even $e^{\text{very}}$, surprised!

Comment: Although "finding" the Jordan canonical form is a sensible task, surely the context of the request is important.  Understanding the distinction between algebraic and geometric multiplicity is crucial but is mentioned only in the Comments.  Asking for "a good step by step method" for $10\times 10$ matrices is not the same as finding a solution for $10^6\times 10^6$ matrices.  Generically all square matrices are close to being diagonalizable (at least over the complex numbers), so examples make more sense for matrices whose entries are somehow known exactly (and admit exact arithmetic).

Answer (score 1):

Here´s the algorithm I know. But a health warning: until you get to reasonably big matrices there is almost always some easier trick. It calculates the JCF, but does not give an explicit similarity.

So suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, with characteristic polynomial $\chi_A(X)$, all of whose roots lie in the field we are working in. (You've got to solve the equation, the algorithm for the JCF only starts once you've done that.)

Now for each of the eigenvalues $\lambda$ we proceed as follows. For $j=1, \dots, n$ we denote by $a_j$ the number of Jordan $j\times j$ blocks associated with $\lambda$: these numbers are what we need to determine. Let $N$ denote for convenience the size of the mega-block corresponding to Jordan blocks of the other eigenvalues.

Calculate (by Gauss Elimination) $r_j:=\text{rank}(A-\lambda I)^{j}$.

Then we have the following equations
$$
\begin{align}
r_0&=a_1+2 a_2+3 a_3+ \dots +n a_n +N\\
r_1&=a_2+2 a_3+ \dots +(n-1) a_n +N\\
r_2&=a_3+2 a_4+ \dots +(n-2) a_n +N\\
\vdots\\
r_n&=N\\
\end{align}
$$
as may be seen at once from the JCF of $A$: similar matrices have the same rank.

These equations determine the number of Jordan blocks of each size and incidentally $N$.

I don't have an example to hand, I'm sorry: and as I say a "typical" example has got to be $10\times 10$ at least!

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_j\}_{j=1}^k$, where $1\leq k\leq n$, associated with the matrix $A$.

2) Find the corresponding eigenvectors $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^k$ where $1\leq k\leq n$.

3) If you have $k=n$, diagonalize the matrix by letting $P$ be the matrix whose $j^{th}$ column is $v_j$ for $j=1$ to $n$ and calculating $P^{-1}AP=D=J$ where the Jordan normal form $J$ is diagonal. If not, proceed to step 4.

4) For each eigenvector $v_j$ you found in step 2, construct a Jordan chain of generalized eigenvectors, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector for several examples.

5) Let $P$ be the matrix whose columns are made up of correctly ordered Jordan chains, then $A=PJP^{-1}$ where $J$ is the almost diagonal Jordan normal form.